# How to restart Glassfish with a commandline command

Tags: java, glassfish, asadmin, undeploy

I would like to achieve the same restart effect as clicking on the Restart button of the glassfish admin web gui (Server->General->Restart) on picture. But I would like to do it via command line

[image]

I have some strange behaviour of the app during undeploy. If I restart the server via GUI ant then do the :
asadmin deploy 
asadmin undeploy

the app undeploys in a few seconds

But If I have the GF server as a windows service and do a restart of the service and after that :
asadmin deploy
asadmin undeploy

the app undeploys in 5 minutes.

So I would like to find the equivalent asadmin command for server restart as via web GUI.

I have already tried:

```
asadmin restart-domain --force=false domain1
asadmin restart-domain --force=true domain1
asadmin stop-domain domain1
asadmin start-domain domain1
```

but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script we use:

```
echo "Stopping the server"
INSTANCES=`asadmin list-instances | grep -v "Command" | cut -d' ' -f1`
for INSTANCE in $INSTANCES; do
    asadmin stop-instance $INSTANCE
done
asadmin stop-domain $DOMAIN

echo "Starting the server"
asadmin start-domain
INSTANCES=`asadmin list-instances | grep -v "Command" | cut -d' ' -f1`
for INSTANCE in $INSTANCES; do
    asadmin start-instance $INSTANCE
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
asadmin start-domain domain1
```

Comment: Please explain the effect of what you propose and why it solves the problem.